# SQL - Rolling 4 Quarters Sales Calculation for each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

This solution does not have to be the most efficient, I just need a dependable SQL query I can run once a quarter to determine the rolling 4 qtr sum of sales for each employee. As you can see multiple records can exist for each employee in each quarter and there can be quarters where employees didn't have any sales. The fiscal year is a little strange, begins on July 1.

[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDboV.png)

```
Record ID   Emp ID  FYQTR   Date    Sales   R4QTR Sales

1   Jamie   FY17Q1  9/08/16 0:00    48900   
2   Jamie   FY17Q2  10/27/16 0:00   507068.2    
3   Jamie   FY17Q2  12/31/16 0:00   49796.75    
4   Jamie   FY17Q3  2/06/17 0:00    37812.52    
5   Jamie   FY17Q4  6/27/17 0:00    110000  
6   Jamie   FY17Q4  6/28/17 0:00    982528.6    
7   Kim     FY17Q4  5/10/17 0:00    162373  
8   Kim     FY17Q4  6/30/17 0:00    1163    
9   Kim     FY18Q1  7/20/17 0:00    755621.35   
10  Kim     FY18Q1  9/30/17 0:00    200000  
11  Terry   FY18Q2  12/31/17 0:00   221846.05   
12  Terry   FY18Q2  12/28/17 0:00   149835.36   
13  Terry   FY18Q2  12/29/17 0:00   50378.37    
14  Terry   FY18Q3  2/22/18 0:00    31214.88    
15  Terry   FY18Q4  4/30/18 0:00    54624.8 

16  Terry   FY18Q4  5/07/18 0:00    31214.88    
17  Terry   FY18Q4  6/29/18 0:00    54624.8 

18  Terry   FY19Q1  8/29/18 0:00    17387.94    
19  Terry   FY19Q1  8/30/18 0:00    74639.06
```

The R4QTR Sales column does not exist right now, it's just where I would like to see the new calculated column. Also I need to keep the structure of the table, the resulting data set should still display all the records at the Record ID level.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you the idea.  However, without a proper database tag, I'm not going to give exact syntax -- date functions differ too much by database.

Convert each quarter to the starting date of the quarter.  Then you can use `range` with an `interval`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(sales) over (partition by emp_id
                        order by qstart
                        range between interval '9 month' preceding and current row
                       ) as running_sum
from (select t.*,
             <logic for first date of quarter here> as qstart
      from t
     ) t;
```

Of course, this assumes that your database support standard `interval` syntax with `range` window frames.

Comment: Not working for me, it seems not to like the Interval syntax